# Solving simulataneous equations with Coffeequate

Tags: javascript, coffeequate

I'm looking for a Computer Algebra System to run in a browser, with a particular interest in finding roots to systems of equations.

I'm currently evaluating Coffeequate.

The simplest non-trivial system I came up with that wasn't on the demo page was a system of two simultaneous linear equations:

```
var exp1 = CQ('x = 2 * y + 6');
var exp2 = CQ('x - y = 10');

exp2.sub({x: exp1.solve('x')})
    .solve('y');
```

Unfortunately, this hangs at the `sub` call.

What I would like to obtain is the value for all unknowns (i.e. `x` and `y`) that are knowable – there is guaranteed to be a solution in this case.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`CQ().solve` returns an *array* of solutions (in case there are multiple solutions). However, things that you want to substitute in using `CQ().sub` have to be integers or `CQ()` objects themselves. The following code works:

```
var exp1 = CQ('x = 2 * y + 6');
var exp2 = CQ('x - y = 10');

exp2.sub({x: exp1.solve('x')[0]}).solve('y'); // 4
```

The fact that it actually hangs instead of erroring when you pass in an array is a bug; I'll patch that.

(Disclaimer: I wrote Coffeequate)

Comment: I want to remove the word 'Disclaimer'. You should shout that from the rooftops. :)